# C program stops accepting input at 1023 characters

Tags: c, debugging

I'm teaching myself C using K&R. Exercise 1-16 asks me to refactor some provided code to give the length of "arbitrarily long input lines".

Whilst working on the problem I found that my terminal ceases to accept input after 1023 characters; a very suspicious number I'm sure you'll agree!! I have tested on Mac OS X and OpenBSD and see the same behaviour. The program hasn't stopped responding because typing backspace and submitting the input works correctly.

I couldn't figure out how to debug this with gdb because the problem occurs during data entry, not after submission when stepping through with gdb.

I could see no reference to a limit in the getchar or bash manpages, and indeed it seems very little input anyway.

I reduced the problem to the following and see the same behaviour.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int c,i=0;

  while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n')
    ++i;
  printf("%d\n",i);

  return 0;
}
```

Could people please explain:

1. Why this is happening
2. How I might debug this kind of issue myself

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not put the test data in a file and pipe it into the program under test?  That will make your tests more consistent and documented anyway.  ie. `cat your_test_data | your_executable`

Comment: the issue of console program(shell)?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of Unix terminal drivers in cooked mode. They have a fixed size input buffer for editing.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton, I don't know why I didn't think of that! The program works perfectly when accepting data like that.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I thought it was something like that I was just barking up the wrong tree with the bash manual.

Comment: Definitely. The shell is just used for starting your program. Once your program is running, the shell is not in the loop at all.

Comment: @retrodev there's numerous other layers than getchar() and bash involved in such a seemingly simple thing as inputting characters to a program - read e.g. http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/ . This limit is outside your program.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments on my question, it would appear to be a terminal limitation. Piping a file into the program works as expected.